# accessible, but out of tabstop sequence

Tags: autohotkey, readonly, tabstop

Is there a way to get an edit control accessible, but out of the tabstop sequence? Eg I have

```
Gui, Add, Text, &a
Gui, Add, Edit, -Tabstop ReadOnly
```

I cannot tab to it (which is good) but i also cannot use alt-a to reach it nor can I reach it by mouse clicking it. This is a problem as the user cannot scroll and peruse its contents.

If one changes the - to a + one can reach it by tabs and alt-a. However I do not want it to be in the tabstop sequence. From the "GUI Styles" page of the AutoHotkey Help/manual these appear to be the only relevant styles for an edit command...

How can I have that control reachable, but outside the tab sequence?

Comment: I can MOUSE there but i am trying to use the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn Alt-a into a hotkey, this is how you get the requested result

```
Gui, Add, Text, ,&a 
Gui, Add, Edit, -Tabstop Readonly vMyEdit, My Content
Gui, Add, Edit
Gui, Show
return

!a::
GuiControl,focus, MyEdit
return
```

Comment: A bit cumbersome, but works!
The text control is an unnecessary appendage now.